# evitar que un nuevo intent se repita en android

Tags: java, android

Hola estoy tratando de crear un intent en android, pero el objectivo es comprobar si el intent existe y si existe, destruirlo y llamar a un nuevo intent con parametros distintos, este es el codigo de llamado.

```
public void Safesearch(String urlgoogle){
        String urlString=(urlgoogle.concat("&safe=active"));
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(urlString));
        intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");
        try {
            startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
            intent.setPackage(null);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: En todo caso que parámetros son los que varían?

Comment: lo unico que cambia es "urlgoogle", como te daras cuenta, cada vez que llamo a ese metodo se crear un nuevo intent, me gustaria, comprobar si ya esta creado.